# Can I use EKS NodePort service with port 80 and 443

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I am using `EKS` (`K8s` service natively provided by `AWS`).

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to expose `NodePort` service through port 80 and 443 (default `NodePort` range is `30000 - 32767`).
2. If it is, how to do that with `EKS`.

**Note** I know the consequences of using `NodePort` services and have researched alternatives like `LoadBalancer` and `Ingress`. I am going ahead with NodePort because I have to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. No. According to the [EKS AMI Source](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-eks-ami), the worker nodes' kubelets use the default configuration for `--service-node-port-range`. You will be assigned an external port number between `30000-32767`.
2. You have the alternative of using the node's **hostNetwork** to expose port 80 and 443 as **hostPort**. A description of the setup can be found [here](http://alesnosek.com/blog/2017/02/14/accessing-kubernetes-pods-from-outside-of-the-cluster/). Just keep in mind the networking constraints and caveats of using a hostNetwork!

Comment: I just recently found out about the `hostPort` and `hostNetwork` too. Thanks for confirming that it is what I need.

Comment: Hi Frank, --service-node-port-range is configuration in kube-apiserver right? Are you saying we can override it at kubelet level?

Comment: From my understanding, when you declare a NodePort, you are assigned a port number in a range given by the Kubernetes system. This range is specified at the Kubelet-level, not the api-server, since each Kubelet may sit in networks with different ACLs and security groups in the wild.

Answer (score 1):

Try using externalIPs for your Service:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: MyApp
  ports:
  - name: http
    protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  externalIPs:
  - node1_IP
  - node2_IP
  - node3_IP
```

In that case port 80 will also be opened on node IPs. This is a dirty workaround but it should work.